# Any idea why my dojo TabContainer is so messed up?

Tags: asp.net, dojo, tabcontainer

I have a website that has a dojo TabContainer. I've been trying to upgrade the dojo library from 1.2 to the later versions.

At 1.5 I've run into a problem.

This is what the TabContainer looks like in FF at 1.5, and what it looked like in the previous versions in all browsers. (IE, Chrome, Safari)

[image: Yay Firefox]

At 1.5, this is what it looks like in IE9

[image: Boo IE]

I can't figure out where these arrow buttons are coming from. The styling and markup hasn't changed, I've just swapped out the dojo libraries.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="TabRepeater" runat="Server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
      <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" gutters="false" style="width:600px">
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width:600px; height:350px">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="display:none; height:300px" title="<%#Eval("Name")%>">
        <!-- Content -->
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </div> <!-- End Tab Container -->
      </div> <!-- End Border Container -->
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

It's pretty basic, I've defined the sizes for the containers. I'm not sure why these scroll buttons won't go away. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my code or with the TabContainer since their [documentation site](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html) doesn't even work in IE9

FF:
[image: Firefox]

IE9:
[image: IE9]

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo 1.5 is not officially compatible with IE9. Compatibility has been officially partially supported since dojo 1.6.x and is supposed to be *fully* compatible with dojo 1.7.x

Also, I do not know much about asp, but this does not look like a good practice

```
<HeaderTemplate>
  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" gutters="false" style="width:600px">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width:600px; height:350px">
</HeaderTemplate>
```

to have a "tag" (except if this tag disappear and is not replaced by any html) enclosing unclosed divs...

Comment: the FooterTemplate will close the divs. Thanks for the answer though. I guess I have no choice but to keep upgrading and hope the problem resolves itself. If no one else has any suggestions over the next few days, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: We had to *run IE9 in IE8 compatibility mode* until we upgraded dojo to 1.6.  Dojo 1.5 definitely had ie9 problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using `dojo 1.10.4`. I was not using asp.net.

I solved this by setting the properties [`useMenu`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/layout/TabContainer#1_10dijit_layout_TabContainer_useMenu) and [`useSlider`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/layout/TabContainer#1_10dijit_layout_TabContainer_useSlider) of the `TabContainer` class:

```
var container = new TabContainer(
  {
    style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%;',
    useMenu: false,
    useSlider: false
  }, domConstruct.create('div'))
```

Thanks to [David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/dojo-tabs#comment-38562).